# How can I include a JS script in a ReactJS page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a simple quiz using JS to be used in a page of my react app. The thing is, I don't know how to include it inside the page file. How do I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of different ways you could do this. You could use react-helment and add the script in a scriptTag like so:

```
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";
const Demo = props => (
        <div>
            <Helmet>
              <script src="/path/to/resource.js" type="text/javascript" />
            </Helmet>
            ...
        </div>
);
```

That is probably the simplest way, but there are other libraries and resources you could use like useEffect from react, or appendScript from utils. You can also add it as a script tag in the head of your base html file and call it from your componentDidMount() function.

Answer (score 0):

HTML for scripts on a page is usually some permutation of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/your/script.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
All your javascript inline here
*/
</script>
```

These are usually either inside the `<head>` tag of the page, if it must execute before everything else or just before the `</body>` tag, if it relies on the page markup.

Answer (score 0):

I was using npm react-script-tag [npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-script-tag) yesterday and it was working pretty good. Its pretty easy to use as well as Helmet like another user suggested.